# Image Uploader throws Uncaught type Error in Ui Component

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, image-upload

I'm Using UI component to upload an image but it throws this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php on line 220 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php:172 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php(220): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('banner', NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Form\Field.php(84): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('banner', 'imageUploader', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent.php(159): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent.php(156): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareC in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php on line 172

My Code for Image Uploader is

```
        <field name="banner">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">flashsalespro</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload Banner</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">PME_FlashSalesPro/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload image for sales background.</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="sales/index/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of this line

```
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
```

I removed it now it is working fine..

Comment: great work @gee Emm

Comment: Any help thanks  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 @Ghulam.M